# embed fonts in pdf with ghostscript in existing file

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I have a figure that I produced in R and another in Excel. That figure contains some axis titles and a plot. However, both figures don't have the fonts embedded in the pdf. I would like to use ghostscript to generate a new pdf file for each figure that has all the requisite fonts embedded. How do I do this on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need not embed the base 14 fonts, these are always required to be present in a reader, though you may do so if you wish.

You will need to have the required fonts available on your system, ideally as PostScript fonts or as CIDFonts, TrueType fonts can be used but can be problematic. You will need to make these fonts available to Ghostscript by editing the cidfmap file or fontmap.GS file in the Program Files/gs/gsx.xx/lib folder. You need to know whether the PDF file uses Fonts or CIDFonts so that you can make the requisite font type available.

Then run the file through Ghostscript, selecting the pdfwrite device, Ghostscript will pick up the installed fonts to use in place of the missing ones in the original PDF file, and the pdfwrite device will embed these in the output PDF file.

Note that the new file is not the same as the old file, you should read the Overview in the VectorDevices.htm documentation to understand the process involved and the limitations this imposes.

In my opinion this question is rather off-topic for Stack Overflow since it does not relate to programming.